# How to avoid nesting closures when mapping Combine arrays?

Tags: swift, combine

I have an array of strings that I would like to map into different objects. I'm using map to transform the array to another, but it's very nested:

```
$favorites
    .map { articleIDs in
        articleIDs.compactMap { id in
            state.articles.first { $0.id == id }
        }
    }
    .assign(to: \Self.favorites, on: self)
    .store(in: &cancellable)
```

Is there a shorthand to applying a transform to each individual item? I was originally trying to do this but it didn't work:

```
state.$favorites
    .mapEach { id in state.articles.first { $0.id == id } }
    .assign(to: \Self.favorites, on: self)
    .store(in: &cancellable)
```

Comment: What type is value?

Comment: Value is an array of Article ID’s. I’ve updated the code for clarity.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, `favorites` is a `[[String]]`, and you're mapping this into `[[Article]]`, and then assign it back to `favorites`? (How is that possible? What type is `favorites`?) I usually try to demonstrate these using `Just` so I can show the entire flow. What's the input and output types?

Comment: I meant I'm trying to map `favorites: [String]` to `[Article]` in one flatting closure, but not sure if it's possible without a custom operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, you:

1. convert a single array into a pipeline of individual elements with `Publishers.Sequence`
2. Process the elements individually.
3. Convert the elements back to an array with the `collect` operator.

Here's a contrived example that you can run in an Xcode playground:

```
import Combine
import UIKit

class MyStore: ObservableObject {
  @Published var favorites: [(id: Int, title: String)] = []
  let articles = [
    (id: 22, title: "foo"),
    (id: 5, title: "bar"),
    (id: 13, title: "baz"),
  ]
  var cancellable: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

  func addFavorites(favorites: AnyPublisher<[Int], Never>) {
    let articles = self.articles
    favorites
      .flatMap(Publishers.Sequence.init)
      .compactMap { fav in articles.first { fav == $0.id }}
      .collect()
      .assign(to: \.favorites, on: self)
      .store(in: &cancellable)
  }
}

let store = MyStore()
store.addFavorites(favorites: Just([22, 13]).eraseToAnyPublisher())
print(store.favorites)
// => [(id: 22, title: "foo"), (id: 13, title: "baz")]
```

... however I suspect this isn't actually what you want. A more elegant solution might be to create a bespoke `compactMapEach` operator. Here's what that looks like:

```
extension Publisher {
  public func compactMapEach<T, U>(_ transform: @escaping (T) -> U?)
    -> Publishers.Map<Self, [U]>
    where Output == [T]
  {
    return map { $0.compactMap(transform) }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx about the flatMap > compactMap > collect pipeline and suggestion of a custom compactMapEach operator!